# Office Word. How to open the same document in separate windows?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2013

How to open the same document in separate windows in Microsoft Office Word? One solution would be to rename it, but is there other better solution?

It is the equivalent of my [previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/480061/acrobat-reader-how-to-open-the-same-document-in-separate-windows) which asked to do the same in Adobe Reader.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

If you'd like to work on different parts of the same document, you can click "View" - "New Window" or "Split". New Window - well, it's quite obvious. "Split" means the 2 windows will be stacked.

Repeat for as many documents as you like. Note that it is still 1 document - edits you do in 1 window will be transferred to all windows.

On older versions of Word the new window command is under the 'window' menu.

Comment: I don't know if it's age or OS, but on OS X (Word:Mac 11) it's also in the Window menu.

Answer (score 3):

Open the document.  Then click File, then Recent, right click on the open document, then Open a Copy.  Same document in two separate windows - done.

Comment: I found Recent on Word 2010, but not on 2013 (Trial)

Answer (score 2):

On current Mac OS as of now (Fall 2021), click the 'Window' tab at the top and then select 'New Window'.

This will open another window of the same document.

Answer (score 1):

You can also right click on the documents icon (in Windows 7) and select "new", this will open a new instance of the same file.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use the usual "split" mode of word, but defining your monitors as extending one above the other (and not side by side as you would usually do). 
It's a little confusing with cursor movement at the beginning, but it the only solution I found (after years of frustration).

Comment: Please take a look at [How to write a good answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Lol, that's actually a good idea, assuming New Window isn't an option.